# Select statement where id is in other table

Tags: php, mysql

So I have two tables setup:

```
=========================
|        Shares         |
=========================
| user_id | other stuff |
=========================
| 1       | bla bla bla |
| 2       | bla bla bla |
=========================

=====================================
|             Followers             |
=====================================
| id   | follower_id | following_id |
=====================================
| 1    | 7           | 1            |
| 2    | 7           | 2            |
=====================================
```

What I want to do is create a feed which displays the "shares", but only for the people that you are following.  Ideally I'd like to do this with one query, as well.

Here an (obviously incorrect) thing that I tried.  For the sake of this example, assume :user_id is the current user (or follower's) ID.

```
select * from shares where count(select * from followers where follower_id = :user_id and following_id = share.id) > 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the tables with something like:

```
select s.* from shares s, followers f
where f.follower_id = :user_id
  and s.user_id = f.following_id
```

That's using the *implicit* join syntax and many people prefer the explicit variant, but it's not really necessary in this simple case.

Comment: i think it's `s.user_id = f.following_id`

Comment: @491243, absolutely right, adjusted to suit, and added in the user_id check as well. Perhaps next time I'll read the full question before vomiting forth my answer :-)